# How do I find User Agent?

Tags: python, api, discord, reddit, praw

I am making a discord bot which will send memes from Reddit and I have used praw for the task.
However I am having trouble finding the user agent which will be used as follows:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT_ID HERE',
                     client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET HERE',
                     user_agent='USER_AGENT HERE')
```

I already have the client_id and client_secret
Would someone explain the point of a user_agent and how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

The `user-agent` is a header you set when making http request - to identify who or what (browser) is making the request.

More information on [User-agent is on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

You must set/choose the `user-agent` yourself.